# Im trying to create a class but this error pops up

Tags: python

im just learning from the book python crash course and while I was in the class section I created a class but when I try to run it my IDE(Pycharm) says invalid syntax error in def__init__(self, name, age):

```
def__init__(self,  name, age):
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

```
class Dog():
"""A simple attempt to model a Dog"""

def__init(self, name, age):
    """Initialize name and age attributes"""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age


def sit(self):
    """Simulate a dog sitting in response to  command"""
    print(self.name.title() + "is now sitting.")
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqH1q.png)
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKLGP.png) image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKLGP.png)

Comment: `def __init__`? Not sure if a typo, but you're missing space and a `__`.

Comment: No space after def and missing double underscores after init

Comment: Indentation and whitespaces are part of the Python syntax. Make sure you use them properly.

Comment: I have also  added the image of my code and error , please see that, ive mistyped code in here , I copied the same code given in the book

Comment: Notice how your IDE is color-coding the various elements of your code?  Notice how that one definition is colored entirely differently than the rest?  That's *telling you something*, you need to pay attention to it.